# The postgresql-x64-10 service on local computer started and then stopped

Tags: postgresql

I need to make some changes in potsgresql.conf file and pg_hba for enabling ssl. After making the changes, i stopped the postgresql server and on trying to start it , i am getting the error as :
The postgresql-x64-10 service on local computer started and then stopped.Some services stop automatically if they are not in use

Also, i notice that the postmaster.pid file gets deleted from postgresql data directory. Can anyone help in resolving this issue

Comment: It is normal for `postmaster.pid` to disappear when the postmaster stops. You probably made an error when updating the config files, the postgresql logs might tell you what the problem is. Could you post the lines you have changed or added to these config files?

Comment: Your changes in configuration files cause errors preventing it to start. There should be details in postgresql logs (their location is configured in postgresql.conf)

Comment: If your only change was to set `ssl = on`, then you probably just have to provice a server certificate `server.crt` and a private key `server.key`. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-SERVER-FILES).

Comment: Hi all, Thanks a lot . I just forgot to put the certificates in the data directory. Once i put all the related certificates at the data directory, services get started properly.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you made a mistake while editing your config file, I do really recommend you to recheck the syntax, for instance for me the error was fixed after correcting the locale value (I've put first en_US), after the correction I've restarted the service and the error is gone